# Permissions denied using i for i in open

Tags: python, permissions

Here is the code I've got:

```
filename = 'C:\\Users\chnyr\Desktop\Python Programs'
var = [i for i in open(filename, 'r+')] 
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '\n']
```

I keep getting an error message below. I am using `pyCharm v3.8`.

```
C:\Users\chnyr\anaconda3\envs\untitled3\python.exe "C:/Users/chnyr/PycharmProjects/untitled3/translate test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chnyr/PycharmProjects/untitled3/translate test.py", line 9, in <module>
    var = [i for i in open('C:\\Users\chnyr\Desktop\Python Programs', 'r+')]
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\chnyr\\Desktop\\Python Programs'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error is you are trying to open a folder using the `open()` method. You can only open files with the method.

Answer (score 0):

In python (and a lot of other languages) `\` is the escape character.This makes coding with windows filesystems rather tricky. You have to escape each escape, by doing `\\` instead of`\`. Aside from this, like Ann zen [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107555/13656598), `open` only works with files. What you probably want is `glob.glob`, from the glob module.

```
import glob
var = [i for i in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\chnyr\\Desktop\\Python Programs\\*.py')]
print(var)
a = []
for i in var:
    a.append(open(i,'r+'))
```